# Show/Hide Panel when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, checkbox

I'd like to show a panel when a checkbox is selected or hide the same when the checkbox is not selected.
Following code works fine when the value of the checkbox changed. 
However, initially (when building the web page) the panel is always shown. Since the checkbox is deselected the outputLabel ("hallo") should not be displayed. Only after selecting the checkbox, the text should be displayed. So, something goes wrong here...

Here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:body>

    <h:form id="myForm">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="myCheckbox" onclick="hideOrShow(this.checked);"/>
        <h:panelGrid id="myPanel" columns="2" >
            <h:outputLabel for="hallo" value="Halli Hallo" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideOrShow(show) {
        var obj = document.getElementById("myForm:myPanel");
        if (show) {
            obj.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            obj.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You could just hide it when document is ready and then toggle between show and hide?

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript for show/hide panel. Here is version of your code with ajax:

```
 <h:form>
     <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="myCheckbox" value="#{helloWorld.checked}">
         <f:ajax event="click" render="myPanel" execute="myPanel" />
     </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
     <h:panelGroup id="myPanel" layout="block">
         <h:outputLabel value="hi there" rendered="#{helloWorld.checked}" />
     </h:panelGroup>
 </h:form>
```

and bean

```
private boolean checked;
public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
```

Comment: Well, i know this works as well but i would like to avoid the server round trip.

Comment: You easily can do it. Some faces (Richfaces, PrimeFaces) allow to read value on client site. Maybe in JSF without frameworks you really need javascript.

Comment: Ok, than I will do it this way. THANKS!!

Comment: Sorry for being late but because of other circumstances I could not further work on this...    I used exactly your code but it does not work. The panelGroup is never rendered.

Comment: If you need it, then you can post your email address and I will send you zipped project with this code. Code is in working condition and was tested.