# every button click display panelGroup component(it contains 3 components)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

every button click display panelGroup component(it contains 3 components).how to do it using jsf or richfaces

```
    <h:form id="autoId">

        <h:panelGroup id="pg1" columns="3" >
        <rich:autocomplete mode="client" minChars="1" autofill="false" 
                           selectFirst="false"
                           autocompleteMethod="#{autocompleteBean.autocomplete}"
                           autocompleteList="#{autocompleteBean.suggestions}"

                           />
        <h:inputText value=""/>
        <h:inputText value=""/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <a4j:commandButton  value="show pg" />
    </h:form>
```

when clicking on commanButton i like to show panelGroup
how to do it

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code and where you got so far?

Comment: Add `rendered` attribute in `h:panelGroup` (false on start) and `render` attribute in `a4j:commandButton`.

Comment: See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274026/show-hide-panel-when-checkbox-is-selected/22277597#22277597) for similar question (in you case it is button, in answer it is check box, but mechanism is the same).